# Run asmx web service on STA

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, fingerprint

I am developing a web application with C# in VS 2012.

I need to execute a Web Service in STAThread mode (because I have a fingerprint sensor which works in Windows Forms). I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163544.aspx) article. I have implemented the class of figure 4 and change the configuration file, but when I execute the project I've got a HTTP 500.23 internal server error which says that "This application defines configuration in the system.web / httpHandlers section." How can I solve this? Or how can I execute a asmx web service in STA mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at article located at. http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications. It several approaches.

If you are using fingerprint sensor, the I guess multithreading should not be a problem ;-).